# difference between '@libreoffice' and 'sudo libreoffice' in LXDE-pi/autostart

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, raspbian

this question is pretty fundamental but i didn't find the right words to google to find an answer
i want to start a presentation on a raspberry pi straight when it boots
So i tested the command to get it to open my presentation, i just used this command:
`sudo libreoffice --impress --nolockcheck --nologo --norestore --show /home/pi/Desktop/Praesentation/1.pptx`
that worked so i put that line into the autostart file at this path:
`/etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart`
That works fine but i found out that you should or can also use this command in the file:
`@libreoffice --impress --nolockcheck --nologo --norestore --show /home/pi/Desktop/Praesentation/1.pptx`

but running the command in the commandline with `bash @libreoffice...` does not work
What does the @ mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you shouldn't be running LibreOffice as root (`sudo`). This will give it full rights to do anything on the system, which is not needed for an office application, and it might cause all sorts of trouble if it writes files owned by the wrong user.

The [LXSession wiki](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/index.php?title=LXSession#autostart_configuration_file) explains what the `@` means:

> #### autostart configuration file
>
> This file stores the commands that will be executed at the beginning of the session. It is not a shell script, but each line represents a different command to be executed. **If a line begins with @, the command following the @ will be automatically re-executed if it crashes.**

Comment: thanks for the link, that explains why i always get the powerpoint to restart when i run the ´pkill soffice.bin´ command
now i am working on finding a way to detect when libreoffice freezes or to prevent it because after some time the presentation just stops and i want that to not happen :P

but for that i will make a new topic when i need help for it
Thanks for the help, have a nice day :D
~Hyperfluff